# How can I prove a function is bijective and get its inverse

Tags: discrete-mathematics, functions, inverse-function

I have the following function $$f:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow\Bbb{R^+}$$

which is defined as $$f(x) = 2^x$$

How do I show that this function is a bijection and find its inverse?

Comment: This is one of those questions where it depends on how deep you wish to delve into the theory, which judging by the current tag and the lack of other context, is probably not much. I'm guessing that all you're required to do is point to the base $2$ logarithm, declare that it's the inverse of $f$, and that it has domain $\Bbb{R}^+$. If you want an answer with more detail than that, we'll need more context than you've given us.

Comment: Take some real value $y>0$ such that ${2^x}=y$ is not satisfied. We can prove that there exists a value for x, and this contradiction makes the function onto. Now take two values of x, $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that$ f{({x_1})}={f({x_2})}$. From this, we get ${x_1}={x_2}$. So the function is one-one. Thus it is bijective, and we can easily find its inverse, i.e. $f(x)={log_2}x$

Comment: @Righter how do I write that?

Comment: Which part do you mean by "that"?

Answer (score 0):

First we prove that the function is onto. Let us assume that it is into.

 Then there exists some real value $y\in\Bbb R^+$ such that there is no real value of x for the condition $$f(x)=2^x=y$$
Taking $log_2$ on both sides, $$x=\log_2 y$$
Since $y>0$, there is a real, defined value of $x$. This is a contradiction. Thus our assumption is incorrect and the function is onto.

Now we prove that the function is one-one. Let us assume that it is many-one.

 Then we can take two real values $x_1$, $x_2$ $\in\Bbb R$ such that $x_1\neq x_2$ and  $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, i.e. $$2^{x_1}=2^{x_2}$$ $$2^{x_1-x_2}=1$$
$$x_1-x_2=0$$
$$x_1=x_2$$
This is a contradiction. Thus our assumption is incorrect and the function is one-one.

 Since the function is both one-one and onto, it is a bijective function.
thus we can find its inverse.
$$$$
To find the inverse, we take $y=f(x)$ and then interchange $x$ and $y$ to get
$$x=2^y$$
$$\log_2 x=y$$
Therefore the inverse function of f(x) is
$$f(x)=\log_2 x$$

Comment: Also, if you want to do this as an objective problem, the graph itself is sufficient to see that the function is bijective (see https://imgur.com/a/qxlno3V)

Comment: Type `$\log_2 x$` to obtain $\log_2 x$ so that you can distinguish the logarithm from the variable.